# Tamper resistant housing methods

Tags: protection, hardware, cases

When creating electronic devices there are times that we want to make it difficult for an unauthorized person to open the device.

I was wondering where there might be a list of methods or common techniques used to accomplish this.

What comes to mind are the following:

- Hiding screws behind stickers
- Special screws (non-standard heads)
- Cover contains contact that closes circuit so when disconnected/open circuit does not power on

What are some other (or more sophisticated) methods available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few off the top of my head:

- [Potting the circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1eJ1oyaJ_Y)
- Chassis Gluing
- Tamper evident stickers

Answer (score 1):

Fasteners with left hand threads, plus a couple of dummy fasteners with right hand threads.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, triangular-headed screws are very hard to remove without the correct tool - especially if surrounded by an annular shield.